# Apache SPARK SVM in Scala vs Python

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, svm

Recently I've been trying to utilize Spark to do binary classification. I code in Python and in order to use Spark SVM, I am using the following package:

```
from pyspark.mllib.classification import SVMWithSGD
```

Looking at [this link](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-linear-methods.html) I realized that Scala version of SVM.predict returns a score while the python version of it returns a label. Since I want to calculate AUROC using:

```
from pyspark.mllib.evaluation import BinaryClassificationMetrics
```

I do need the scores rather than the labels of the test samples. Reading spark official documentation I figured unfortunately the python version as mentioned earlier only returns the labels. Please correct me if I am wrong or help me to resolve this problem (if you are aware of any other packages or something).

Thanks

Comment: That's correct, but what is the question?

Comment: @eliasah any method in python spark svm which returns the score rather than the label?

Comment: Nope. You'll have to tweak it yourself. You can also write your own evaluation classes. That's what I do since they are still not all available even in Scala.

Comment: Unfortunately. But it doesn't make any sense, they are supposed to be compatible with each other, aren't they?

Comment: Nope. They are not supposed to be now, but eventually they will be. There is lots of work on standardizing the APIs. Nevertheless, Python doesn't run in a JVM and also it uses numpy which doesn't have the same structural definition as in Scala or Java. Thus, the inconsistency between APIs. But the Apache Spark team is working on it. The project is very complex and huge with all the libraries to maintain and also with the Tungsten project in the pipes. So you just have to be patient and tweak your own solution around it meanwhile. That's what I do.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for the help anyways.

Comment: You can follow the workflow of the Spark project on JIRA and you can also raise issues and participate in the project if you wish. Make sure to read the guidelines first!

Answer (score 3):

As @eliasah has pointed out you could extend `SVMModel` to add a a function which returns what you are looking for:

```
def predictRaw(self, x):
    """
    Predict values for a single data point or an RDD of points
    using the model trained.
    """
    if isinstance(x, RDD):
        return x.map(lambda v: self.predict(v))

    x = _convert_to_vector(x)
    margin = self.weights.dot(x) + self.intercept
    return margin
```

I went to go implement parameter clearing so you can do it as with the Scala API, and it seems like it already should work for you, simply call `clearThreshold` on the model and predict will switch to returning the margin as with the Scala API.

Comment: Thanks for your useful comment Holden. I will also give this a shot and let you know about the results.